# Find a Transformation Matrix

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

So I have two bases in R3. To find the transformation matrix, I have to solve a system of linear equations.

I have these
[image]

Gaussian Elimination for v:

[image]

Gaussian Elimination for w:

[image]

So v and w are bases. To calculate the transformation matrix, solve

[image]

with

[image]

And this is where it gets too much for me. How do I get these numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you have:

$\begin{bmatrix}w_{11}&w_{12}&w_{13}\\w_{21}&w_{22}&w_{23}\\w_{31}&w_{32}&w_{33}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}v_{11}&v_{12}&v_{13}\\v_{21}&v_{22}&v_{23}\\v_{31}&v_{32}&v_{33}\end{bmatrix}$

so now you need $a_{ij}$ Matrix

You can augment Matrix V to Matrix W. And find Reduced Row echoleon form

from there, you can easly get A matrix ,
Suppose u get RREF as:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&v'_{11}&v'_{12}&v'_{13}\\0&1&0&v'_{21}&v'_{22}&v'_{23}\\0&0&1&v'_{31}&v'_{32}&v'_{33}\end{bmatrix}$
now $a_{11}$=$v'_{11}$, similarly $a_{21}$=$v'_{21}$... so on